# IncompatibleClassChangeError when using HtmlUnit in java in Intelli

Tags: java, intellij-idea, htmlunit

I am trying to use HtmlUnit with the following code in java in IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.3.6

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
}
```

It is a gradle project so I have this in my build.gradle

```
compile 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.36.0'
```

But when I ran the above one line program from Intellij, I got such error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle can not implement org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container, because it is not an interface (org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3062)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2249)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.process(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:298)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.getClassConfiguration(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:204)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.buildUsageMap(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:85)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.<init>(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:65)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.<init>(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:603)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:619)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.<init>(JavaScriptEngine.java:141)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:249)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:227)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:219)
at com.tripadvisor.flights.partners.travix.TravixProcessor.main(TravixProcessor.java:10)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like incompatibe jars in your classpath.

Comment: @Jens any idea which jar this could be? We use gradle to manage all jars

Answer (score 0):

Tried with a brand new project and it worked. So it must be caused by one of the dependencies of the old project already included htmlunit jar that has an incompatible version with the htmlunit jar I want to include here